# Latest Windows threadpool API usage for I/O

Tags: windows, sockets, io, threadpool

I don't understand part of the latest Windows threadpool API. I need help with that.

From the documentation, the recipe to use it for I/O (in my case, for SOCKET) can be summarized as follows:

1. Call CreateThreadpoolIo.
2. Call [StartThreadpoolIo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686326(v=vs.85).aspx). You can find this warning there:

   > You must call this function before initiating each asynchronous I/O operation on the file handle bound to the I/O completion object. Failure to do so will cause the thread pool to ignore an I/O operation when it completes and will cause memory corruption.
3. Call the operation on the file handle (e.g., WSARecvFrom). If it fails, call [CancelThreadpoolIo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681983(v=vs.85).aspx). Otherwise, process the result when it is available. WSARecvFrom, when used asynchronously, asks for a WSAOVERLAPPED (that you have to create beforehand) but not for any information that links it to the previous call to StartThreadpoolIo. CancelThreadpoolIo only asks for the PTP_IO, but not for any additional information to derive a specific asynchronous operation.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3.
5. Call CloseThreadpoolIo to finish. You can find this warning there:

   > It may be necessary to cancel threadpool I/O notifications to prevent memory leaks. For more information, see CancelThreadpoolIo.

I usually need it for UDP, so I strive to have several reception operations queued (asynchronous WSARecvFrom operations started) at any given time. That way I don't have to rush to start another reception operation at the beginning of the callback function nor synchronize access to the reception buffers (I can have a pool of them, each one able to contain a datagram, and reissue the reception operation when I finish processing each message; in the interim, other queued operations will keep the receiver busy). Datagrams are independent and self contained. I'm aware that this approach may not be valid for TCP.

StartThreadpoolIo/CancelThreadpoolIo seem to me the source of the problem: StartThreadpoolIo and WSARecvFrom are not directly bound (they don't share any arguments). So:

**How can the framework know which operation to cancel when you call CancelThreadpoolIo? How does it cancel just the operation that failed and not any of the pending ones?**

You can say, "don't call StartThreadpoolIo concurrently". I can live without several concurrent WSARecvFrom's, but I can't live without concurrent WSARecvFrom and WSASendTo. So I think being unable to have several asynchronous operations at the same time can't be the way the API was designed.

You can say, "call StartThreadpoolIo only once, that will suffice to register the callback; it is an on/off process". But the documentation says:

> You must call this function before initiating each asynchronous I/O operation on the file handle...

You can say, "it cancels the operation started by the same thread that just called StartThreadpoolIo". But then the advice of calling CancelThreadpoolIo in the context of calling CloseThreadpoolIo doesn't make sense (I will call CloseThreadpoolIo from the thread that triggers stopping, which will be completely independent from the threads issuing the asynchronous operations; and a single call to CancelThreadpoolIo may not be enough to cancel several operations). Being unable to trigger cancellation from a different thread is a serious limitation, anyway. I'm aware of the existence of CreateThreadpoolCleanupGroup, but my question is more fundamental. I want to understand how this API can be fundamentally right and useful.

You can say "call CreateThreadpoolIo several times, so that you have independent PTP_IO's to work with". It doesn't work. When I call CreateThreadpoolIo a second time, nullptr is returned.

Am I wrong, or is this API awkward? Normally, other asynchronous APIs work with one of these patterns:

1. Create an operation and receive a handle => call methods passing the handle.
2. Create a reusable handle => call methods (including starting operations) passing the handle.

The latest Windows threadpool API, in which the handle seems to be implicit, or there are several handles for the same operation (TP_IO, WSAOVERLAPPED, StartThreadpoolIo) and they aren't all explicitly linked together, uses neither of them.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: From my reading of the documentation, calling CancelThreadPoolIo doesn't actually cancel the I/O operation, which after all is already complete.  It just tells the thread pool not to expect a completion notification for it.  In other words, my guess is that the thread pool needs to keep count of how many I/O operations are pending on a given file handle, and StartThreadPoolIo/CancelThreadPoolIo are all about keeping the count correct.

Comment: >> When I call CreateThreadpoolIo a second time, nullptr is returned.

That's because of underlying mechanism below threadpool-based IO. Internally this CreateThreadpoolIo() thing associates a completion port with your handle, and StartThreadpoolIo)( guarantees that there is a threadpool thread ready and waiting on the completion port. You can't have two completion ports per one handle.

If you want to better understand how Vista threadpool works, study carefully how WIndows 2000 threadpool works (as in, BindIoCompletionCallback()) and think how you will write a better abstratction

Comment: @HarryJohnston could you ever confirm your suspicion about the counter?

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia, I never saw any point in trying - that's an implementation detail, after all, subject to change.  It seems clear enough how to use the API, as per my comment and Sergei's answer, that's all that really matters.

Answer (score 1):

> > How can the framework know which operation to cancel when you call CancelThreadpoolIo? How does it cancel just the operation that failed 
> >     and not any of the pending ones?

CancelThreadpoolIo() doesn't cancel IO. It is reciprocal to StartThreadpoolIo(). StartThreadpoolIo() prepares threadpool to accept a completion. If threadpool doesn't expect a completion, it won't wait for it, thus you may miss it. If threadpool expects a completion but completion doesn't happen, threadpool may waste resources.

CancelThreadpoolIo() undoes whatever StartThreadpoolIo() did.

Comment: "thus you may miss it" — in my case, the miss were a second-chance AV, which is not very fun.

The real question is, do `Start-` calls pile up, and does `Cancel-` undo just one from that pile — or `Start-` just changes the state to "ready for callback" no matter how many times called, and `Cancel-` undoes that all. Intuitively I'd rather believe in the increment-decrement picture, but I'd rather see it explicitly written in documentation.